# Windows 10 Calculator No Longer Works

Tags: windows-10, calculator

Another, stupid Windows 10 qerk.
I am fully updated with an activated version of Win 10 installed from fresh, **NOT** an upgrade.

Everything on my start works, but if I search for Calculator from All Apps it is not listed. If I search in Start Search, by typing Calc or Calculator, I get:: "@ {Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1601.49 Desktop App". If I click this, nothing happens.

If I goto Windows Store, Calculator is shown as installed.

If I try and do "Start>Run>Calc" which always worked perfectly before, I get the following.....

[image: Start>Run>Calc shows this]

WTF is going on?!

Comment: Do you see it here: C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

Comment: Did you by chance "uninstall" or disable Windows Store applications?  This type of behavior is normally done by hacks that attempt to "block" Windows 10 from "spying".  In this state a Refreshing the installation is your only solution.

Comment: Since the store says it is installed, try un-installing it and re-installing it again..

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish yup its there but it shows the same box as in the op.

Comment: @Ramhound, no have not messed, it is a fresh install, all I have done is Win updates.

Comment: @KodyBrown, ok, how can I re-install, or uninstall? I can't see that option? It just says product is installed.

Comment: I ran SFC /scannow and got the following back:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.

Comment: Windows 10 is so awesome!

Comment: @Moab hmm, I will reserve my judgement on that.

Comment: It was meant to be a joke....a bad one at that.

Comment: @moab don't worry, I know. Not as much of a joke a Microsoft Windows 10! No wonder it is a free upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

- Press Windows key + I to open Settings.
- Open Apps and select Apps & Features.
- Find Calculator app and click it.
- Click on the Advanced options link to open Storage usage and app reset page.
- Click Reset and once again Reset button on the confirmation window.